# Linear Regression with a known fixed intercept in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

I want to calculate a linear regression using the lm() function in R. Additionally I want to get the slope of a regression, where I explicitly give the intercept to `lm()`.

I found an example on the internet and I tried to read the R-help "?lm" (unfortunately I'm not able to understand it), but I did not succeed. Can anyone tell me where my mistake is?

```
lin <- data.frame(x = c(0:6), y = c(0.3, 0.1, 0.9, 3.1, 5, 4.9, 6.2))
plot (lin$x, lin$y)

regImp = lm(formula = lin$x ~ lin$y)
abline(regImp, col="blue")

# Does not work:
# Use 1 as intercept
explicitIntercept = rep(1, length(lin$x))
regExp = lm(formula = lin$x ~ lin$y + explicitIntercept)
abline(regExp, col="green")
```

Thanls for your help.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You could subtract the explicit intercept from the regressand and then fit the intercept-free model:

```
> intercept <- 1.0
> fit <- lm(I(x - intercept) ~ 0 + y, lin)
> summary(fit)
```

The `0 +` suppresses the fitting of the intercept by `lm`.

**edit** To plot the fit, use

```
> abline(intercept, coef(fit))
```

P.S. The variables in your model look the wrong way round: it's usually `y ~ x`, not `x ~ y` (i.e. the regressand should go on the left and the regressor(s) on the right).

Comment: or `I(x - 1.0)~ y-1` surpresses the fitting of the intercept as well.

Comment: @Joris Meys: Yes. I believe the two ways are synonymous. I chose the other way to avoid having two `-1` terms and having to explain which is which.

Comment: But when I plot the regression-curve abline(regExp, col="green"), it does not go through 1. I have not figured out how to extract the slope (and/or intercept) from the lm ouput. For mee it seems that you always have to know the position of the values in the coef-array, and than extract in (and hope that the position is right). So, is the following code the "golden way" to plot the correct regression curve? `abline(b=coef(regExp)[1], a= explicitIntercept, col="green")`

Comment: @Sven: `abline(1.0, coef(fit))` plots the fit (here, 1.0 is the explicit intercept). I've updated the answer to include this.

Comment: See also the `offset` argument.

Comment: `offset` can be used either as an argument or as a term in the model. (You were posting your comment as the same time as I was offering an alternate answer.)

Comment: `fit = lm(x~0+y, lin)` will have the effect of forcing the line through the origin then? Thanks.

Comment: @qed, no, `y - 1` will. Try `abline(lm(x ~ y - 1, data=lin))`.

Answer (score 22):

I see that you have accepted a solution using I(). I had thought that an offset() based solution would have been more obvious, but tastes vary and after working through the offset solution I can appreciate the economy of the I() solution:

```
with(lin, plot(y,x) )
lm_shift_up <- lm(x ~ y +0 + 
                       offset(rep(1, nrow(lin))), 
             data=lin)
abline(1,coef(lm_shift_up))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used both offset and I(). I also find offset easier to work with (like BondedDust) since you can set your intercept.

Assuming Intercept is 10.

`plot (lin$x, lin$y)
fit <-lm(lin$y~0 +lin$x,offset=rep(10,length(lin$x)))
abline(fit,col="blue")`