# R draw (abline + lm) line-of-best-fit through arbitrary point

Tags: r, plot, line, point, least-squares

I am trying to draw a least squares regression line using `abline(lm(...))` that is also forced to pass through a particular point. I see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333203/linear-regression-with-explicit-intercept-in-r) is related, but not quite what I want. Here's an example:

```
test <- structure(list(x = c(0, 9, 27, 40, 52, 59, 76), y = c(50, 68, 
79, 186, 175, 271, 281)), .Names = c("x", "y"))

# set up an example plot
plot(test,pch=19,ylim=c(0,300),
     panel.first=abline(h=c(0,50),v=c(0,10),lty=3,col="gray"))

# standard line of best fit - black line
abline(lm(y ~ x, data=test))

# force through [0,0] - blue line
abline(lm(y ~ x + 0, data=test), col="blue")
```

This looks like:

[image]

Now how would I go about forcing a line through the marked arbitrary point of `(x=10,y=50)` while still minimising the distance to the other points?

```
# force through [10,50] - red line
??
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A rough solution would be to  shift the origin for your model to that point and create a model with no intercept

```
nmod <- (lm(I(y-50)~I(x-10) +0, test))

abline(predict(nmod, newdata = list(x=0))+50, coef(nmod), col='red')
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. Doesn't seem that rough a solution.

Comment: Rough? Not from a computing point of view, but rather from a statistical one. You will find a few rants on the subject by Bill Venables (as from Venables/Ripley MASS)

Comment: That's alright, I'm not using this for anything serious, it was more of a thought project. I'll have a bit of a read re: the statistical issues.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the formula for `lm()` and offset the data:

```
p=10
q=50

abline(lm(I(y-q) ~ I(x-p) + 0, data=test), col="red")
```