# How to plot a fitted abline to some data?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, intercept

Guided by the answer to this post:

[Linear Regression with a known fixed intercept in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333203/linear-regression-with-explicit-intercept-in-r)

I have fit an explicit intercept value to some data, but also an explicit slope, thus:

```
intercept <- 0.22483 
fit <- lm(I(Response1 - intercept) ~ 0 + offset(-0.07115*Continuous))
```

Where Response1 is my dependent variable and Continuous is my explanatory variable, both from [this dataset](http://pastebin.com/4wiFrsNg).

I want to plot an abline for my relationship.  When only the intercept has been specified the post above recommends:

```
abline(intercept, coef(fit))
```

However I have no coefficients in the model "fit" as I specified them all.  Is there a way to plot the abline for the relationship I specified?

Comment: What's the purpose of fitting a model where you constrain the slope and intercept? If you do that, then you are imposing a model, which you could plot easily since you already know the slope and intercept.

Comment: Hi Thomas, i'm fitting an intercept and slope from a separate dataset to this dataset to see how well it fits the second dataset, though maybe this isn't the correct way to do this?  Anyhow, I realise that yes, I can just specify the slope in abline(intercept, -0.07115) - stupid questionm, sorry!

Comment: Regardless of the appropriateness of the model, if you know both the slope and intercept, I have to ask again, why you don't simply pass the slope to `abline` directly?

Comment: Hi Joran - yes it was a silly question!  I'm overcomplicating things.

Comment: Just answer it yourself, then, so you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Since it's based on another dataset, you could pass them programmatically based the other dataset (i.e., build the first model, then plot the second data and the `abline` based on coefs from the first dataset).

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that's what i'm doing, i just stupidly overlooked how simple it was to fit the abline :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution that I overlooked.  I know the slope and the intercept so I can just pass them to abline directly:

```
abline(0.22483, -0.07115)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you can do this programmatically, without having to manually put in values. Here's an example with sample data from two similar dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Response1=rnorm(100,0,1), Continuous=rnorm(100,0,1))
df2 <- data.frame(Response1=rnorm(100,0,1), Continuous=rnorm(100,0,1))
fit1 <- with(df1, lm(Response1 ~ Continuous))
with(df2, plot(Response1 ~ Continuous)) # plot df2 data
abline(coef(fit1)) # plot df1 model over it
```