# Linear regression with specified slope

Tags: r, regression

I want to fit a linear regression line with a specified slope to a data set. I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333203/linear-regression-with-explicit-intercept-in-r?lq=1) about doing the same with an explicit intercept.

`0+` suppresses the fitting of the intercept; what is the corresponding trick for the slope? 
For example, to fit a line with slope 1.5, I tried the following

```
set.seed(6)
x <- runif(100, -3, 3) 
y <- 2 + x + rnorm(100) 

model1<-lm(y ~ x) 
plot(x,y)
abline(model1,col="red")
abline(coef(model1),1.5,col="dark green")
```

but second abline function just takes the intercept from model1 and slope 1.5. Whereas I would like the regression line to have slope 1.5, find the best fit to the data points, and then compute intercept from that regression line.

Comment: Ine way is to use the offset... `model2 <- lm(y ~ 1 + offset(1.5*x)) ; abline(coef(model2)[1], 1.5, col="red")` (where you still cant just pass the model object to abline)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose one approach would be to subtract `1.5*x` from `y` and then fit `y` using only an intercept term:

```
mod2 <- lm(I(y-1.5*x)~1)
plot(x, y)
abline(mod2$coefficients, 1.5)
```

[image]

This represents the best linear fit with fixed slope 1.5. Of course, this fit is not very visually appealing because the simulated slope is 1 while the fixed slope is 1.5.

Answer (score 11):

To find the value of the intercept, you don't actually need a regression. Since `Y = a + b * X + ϵ`, then `E[Y - b * X] = E[a] + E[ϵ]`, and by assumption `E[a] = a` and `E[ϵ] = 0`, where `E[]` is the expectation operator. Therefore, `a = E[Y - b * X]`.

Translated into R, this means the intercept `a` is:

```
b1 <- 1.5
a <- mean(y - b1 * x)
```

This is inspired by the comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016892/performing-linear-regression-on-r-with-fixed-slope).