# ggplot smooth pass aes variable to method.args

Tags: r, ggplot2

After many google searches I decided to ask for your help, guys.

I am plotting just some observations at different time points and I want to add a linear regression with stat_smooth. However, I want the linear model with the intercept at 100 (because data are percentage relative to time 0). To do that, I found that the easiest way is to use the offset parameter in lm. The problem is how to get the number of 'y' observations per group(col and facet groups) to pass it to offset parameter.

If I use data with the same number of observations per group (10 in my case), I can just write the number and it works great:

```
myplot <- ggplot(mydt2, aes(x=Time_point, y=GFP_rel, col=Gene, fill=Gene,group=Gene))
myplot <- myplot + stat_smooth(method='lm', formula = y ~ x + 0, method.args=list(offset=rep(100,10))) + 
  facet_wrap(~Cell_line)
```

[image]

However, this is not very elegant and/or flexible. My question is: how can I pass the number of observations to method.args? I tried offset(100,..count..), but I get the error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer').

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some data?

Comment: I would do it, but I am not sure how. I cannot edit the question.

Comment: Thanks @aosmith. I had already tried it, but it plots the data relative to zero instead of 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `I(y - 100)` coding in the formula as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7333292/2461552) instead of using an offset.

However, the predicted values for `stat_smooth` will then be predictions for `y - 100`, not `y`.  This line will go through 0.  You can move the lines back to the position to display predictions of the original `y` variable using `position_nudge`.

So the `stat_smooth` code would look something like

```
stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = I(y - 100) ~ x + 0, 
            position = position_nudge(y = 100))
```

Comment: Thanks @aosmith. The position_nudge solved the offset.