# lm in R - possible to force it to go through a certain point?

Tags: r, lm

I am running a simple regression in R with Price and Quantity:

```
  MyModel=lm(MyData$Price ~ MyData$CumQuantity)
  MyCoef=coef(MyModel)
```

Then the slope will be `MyCoef[2]`, while the intercept will be `MyCoef[1]`.

Is it possible to force it to go through a certain point (a Price and a Quantity), and then get the slope and intercept for that line instead?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this solve the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333203/linear-regression-with-a-known-fixed-intercept-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *minor* variation on the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333203/linear-regression-with-a-known-fixed-intercept-in-r) (which specified an intercept, but not an (x,y) value)

I think this should set the (0,0) point (implicitly) to (`target_CumQuantity`, `target_Price`) and fit a model without intercept (i.e. going through (0,0)).  There will be no intercept estimate, only a slope estimate.  You'd have to work out the intercept estimate by hand ...

```r
MyModel <- lm((Price - target_Price) ~ I(CumQuantity - target_CumQuantity) - 1, 
              data = MyData)
intercept <- with(myData,
    target_Price - target_CumQuantity * coef(MyModel)[1])
```